# Simple Python Program - unsure with While loop

Tags: python

My program is as follows:

```
#Question 6_2010.py

PlayerOneScore=0
PlayerTwoScore=0

    NoOfGamesInMatch=(int(input('How many games in the match?')))
    NoOfGamesPlayed=1+NoOfGamesInMatch

    for NoOfGamesPlayed in range(NoOfGamesInMatch):
        while NoOfGamesInMatch!=NoOfGamesPlayed:
            PlayerOneWinsGame=(input('Did Player One win the game (enter Y or N)?'))    
        if PlayerOneWinsGame=='Y':
            PlayerOneScore = PlayerOneScore + 1
        else:
            PlayerTwoScore = PlayerTwoScore + 1

    print(PlayerOneScore)
    print(PlayerTwoScore)
```

It is nothing complicated. I've just started Python so I'm a bit confused with the loops. When run, the program does as it should - it prints `"'Did Player One win the game (enter Y or N)?')"` the amount of times I enter for `NoOfGamesInMatch`, however, when it prints the player scores, it only does 1 0 either way, depending on if 'Y' is entered or not. If I enter 8 games, 5 'Y' and 3 'N' (or any other character) it should print PlayerOneScore as 5 and PlayerTwoScore as 3 but it only does 10 either way.

What am I missing from my while loop? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your indentation is simply off, so that the increments are happening outside the `while` loop:

```
for NoOfGamesPlayed in range(NoOfGamesInMatch):
    while NoOfGamesInMatch!=NoOfGamesPlayed:
        PlayerOneWinsGame=(input('Did Player One win the game (enter Y or N)?'))    

        # Keep the if/else inside the while loop
        if PlayerOneWinsGame=='Y':
            PlayerOneScore = PlayerOneScore + 1
        else:
            PlayerTwoScore = PlayerTwoScore + 1
```

Note that in its present form, you'll have to actually enter the quoted string `"Y"` rather than just `Y`.

#### Update

Actually, after testing this I realize that you don't even need the `while` loop. Having it in there (even if you increment `NoOfGamesPlayed` multiples the number of games.  Just use:

```
for NoOfGamesPlayed in range(NoOfGamesInMatch):
   PlayerOneWinsGame=(input('Did Player One win the game (enter Y or N)?'))    

    if PlayerOneWinsGame=='Y':
        PlayerOneScore = PlayerOneScore + 1
    else:
        PlayerTwoScore = PlayerTwoScore + 1
```

Comment: Yep. Figured that myself after fixing the indenting. I thought I would need it since it wasn't doing as I wanted but it was just indenting that was the problem.